# Attribute methods derived from System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute class are not called in Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I want to derive an attribute from `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` as follows:

```
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using WebApi = System.Web.Http;

namespace Memzuc.Net.Authorization {
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AuthorizeAttribute : WebApi.AuthorizeAttribute {
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public AuthorizeAttribute() : base() {
            logger.Debug("Memzuc.Net.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute ctor");
        }

        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
            logger.Debug("Memzuc.Net.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute.IsAuthorized called");
            return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
            logger.Debug("Memzuc.Net.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization called");
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Sure I shall do some other useful things! And I use this attribute like so:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using MemAuth = Memzuc.Net.Authorization;

namespace Memzuc.Net.Controllers {
    [RoutePrefix("main-risk")]
    public class MainRiskController : ApiController {
        [Route("")]
        [MemAuth.Authorize]
        public IEnumerable<MainRisk> Get() {
            var repo = GetMainRiskRepo();
            return repo.GetMainRiskList();
        }
```

I see ctor records in the log when the application begins. But both `IsAuhorized()` and `OnAuthorization()` are not get called and `MainRiskController.Get()` method is entered without any authorization control.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it necessary to register the new authorization attribute to somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The attribute and the controller that use it resides in different assemblies, which are referencing different versions of System.Web.Http. As the same version referenced the attribute worked.